# Can exceptions still interrupt the execution when they are wrapped in an appropriate try/except block?

Tags: python, exception, pip, debugpy

I have some debugging code  (involving `debugpy.connect()`) in a custom package, which is expected to raise an exception if the debug server isn't currently launched. The thing is, that code is wrapped in a `try / except Exception` clause, as I don't want it to interrupt the execution of the programs that call it when I'm not debugging (it's just there if I need it).

But then, when `pip install` tries to install that package in my virtual environment, it fails at that point, with a Traceback that make it look as if the exception wasn't caught.

This seems particularly weird to me. Outside of `pip install`, it works as expected and the exception is caught, and the program keeps running.

I've also tried with a bare `except` clause, it also let the exception "escape". I tried researching this on Google, looking at all the possible ways an exception might not be properly caught, and I couldn't find anything.

Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: I should try to reproduce it with minimal code, I'll have to do it sometime.

Comment: It's not clear what exception is causing `pip` to exit (not crash: the traceback is a planned response, a controlled exit in the face of an exception with no other way to handle it.) Are you saying you have code that executes at *installation*? Whatever code you are installing probably shouldn't care if your debug server is running or not until that code is *executed*.

Comment: @chepner "exit (not crash)" you're right, thanks for clarifying. | "you have code that executes at installation?" it's not necessarily meant to, but since it is in a `__init__` module, I guess it does. | "shouldn't care if your debug server is running or not until" exactly! Which is the point of putting it in a try/except (try to connect; doesn't work? just ignore it). But it still manages to interrupt the `pip install`.

Comment: You need to show this code you think is executing and incorrectly letting the exception go uncaught.